# How to chain two splice methods in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, splice

In the following example, splice().splice() didn't work.  What am I missing?  How can I chain two splice methods in a single line?  Thank you for any advice!

```
function test() {

  var data = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
  data.splice(0,2).splice(-1);  // Removed only the first two elements, but not the last element.
  console.log(data) // Returned [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

  var data = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
  data.splice(0,2); // Removed the first two elements.
  data.splice(-1);  // Removed the last element.
  console.log(data) // Returned [ 2, 3, 4 ]

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`splice` returns the removed elements, so chaining them in a single statement won't really work - you don't want to operate on the removed elements, you want to operate on the original array both times.

Usually, in this sort of situation, the right approach is to use `slice` instead, which is both easier to work with (just specify a start (inclusive) and end (exclusive) index) *and* is more functional (you get a new array instead of mutating an existing one - it's nice to avoid mutation when possible, makes code more understandable).

```js
const data = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(data.slice(2,5));
```

Comment: "just specify a start and *after*-end index" ;)

Comment: Thanks!  Now it's clear to me.

Comment: you need no end index. if not specified, it take the rest of the array.

Comment: @NinaScholz OP wants to exclude the final item of the array, not include it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, sorry, didn't read.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, although I don't recommend this because it makes the code confusing

```js
const data = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(data.splice(2,4).splice(0,3)); // Returned [2,3,4]
```